# When should I connect to my database from php scripts?

Tags: php, mysql

I have pages on my site that use the database and pages that don't.

When ever I need the database, I connect using `$conn = connect()`. But this means I need to put it in everywhere its needed. If I put it in an include file and put that file into every page it would connect even when the database is not needed. Would this be a good idea? Would creating a connection cause problems or other issues when not needed, or should I connect only when needed?

Comment: Would creating a function in an included path cause problems if it's not needed/called?

Comment: [Lazy loading](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_loading) a database connection on demand is a good idea.

Comment: Some more code please?

Comment: Go for the include file but only use it in pages that are going to connect. Connections can carry an big execution time overhead - why repeat it throughout one script. If you're using mysqli - try using prepare and bind_params too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Connecting to a database when you don't need to introduces a small amount of overhead that is avoidable. If you need your pages to run as fast as possible, then you could optimize by avoiding the unnecessary db connection.

How much overhead this represents as a proportion of your total PHP execution time varies, for instance if your PHP script is simple and quick, then proportionally the db connection is a larger percentage of the total time wasted. If your PHP script does a lot of other things, then the db connection is a smaller percentage of total time.

Also the speed of a db connection can vary, depending on the speed of your server, whether MySQL is configured with DNS dependency, etc.

When I worked on the Zend Framework, we implemented "lazy" connections. You can create an instance of a Zend_Db_Adapter object anytime you want, but that class doesn't connect to the class constructor. It connects to the database when you run your first query (or when you explicitly call the `getConnection()` method).

Another consideration is how soon do you *disconnect* from the database when you're done running queries.

Suppose you handle 1000 PHP requests per second (one per millisecond on average), and each of your PHP requests lasts 100ms. So at any given instant, you may have 100 PHP requests in progress on average.  If the first thing your PHP code does is connect to the db, and the last thing it does is disconnect from the db and other resources (by automatic request cleanup), then you may also have 100 db connections active at any time.

But if you delay connecting to the db, and disconnect promptly when you are done querying the db, and avoid connecting altogether on some requests, then on average you will have a much lower number of concurrent db sessions.

This can help reduce resource use on the db server, allowing more throughput and a higher number of PHP requests to complete per second.

Comment: Good explanation, but in general you'll need a database pretty soon in the process, querying the database will consume the largest part of the request, and you may not know exactly whether you will need the connection for another request or not. All in all, this theory might not work as well in practise, but +1 nonetheless. At least the theory adds up, and implementing lazy connecting is a breeze to implement, so you can do that anyway.

Comment: @GolezTrol, yeah, I agree that realistically, you're not likely to reduce the average duration of db connections by 90%. But even if you can reduce it by 20% (including some subset of requests that don't need to connect at all because you did lazy connections), then that's an extra 20% of connection capacity on your db server that will benefit you.